# Selenium: move mouse to element doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, element, move, mousemove

I am trying to take the time in the popup which only appears when I move mouse cursor on it. Then move mouse to another point. I tried with firefox and phantomjs on osx and ubuntu. Phantomjs never works, with Firefox it sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't, sometimes movetoelement works, movebyoffset doesn't. I tried wait and sleep functions too, same result. Page is ajax content. I am facing the same issue when I try to click a "href=javascript" button. What can be the problem?

```
movetoelement=css(".content")
action = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element(movetoelement)
action.perform()
time = css('.time').text
print time
actionoffset = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
actionoffset.move_by_offset(10,10)
actionoffset.perform()
```

It requires login, so I can show you the html. There is no problem with my css path. As I said, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
> This is for the element to hover on.
> 
> <a class="tLink event ajaxify" href=“url"
> ajaxtarget="mainLeftContent”>contentbody</a>
> 
> This is for the button
> 
> <a id=“pressbutton" class="tButton large blue" href="javascript:"
> onclick="xcoupon.fn.openPreview()" bt-xtitle="" title=“">Continue</a>
```

Comment: Could you post the url you're accessing this information from?

Comment: I edited the question, you can see there.

Comment: Are there any other elements with the `content` class?

Comment: No there aren't. First I thought that it is about website like you but then I see that move_by_offset sometimes doesn't work too, so it cannot be about website.

Comment: I asked for the url so that tests or further examination could be done, but as you said, login is required (unless there is some page on the site that could access similar information without a login)

Comment: The content which I am trying to take, requires login. But as I said, if it is about website then why wouldn't move_by_offset work?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was about the website. For instance, if access to the direct page would have been available, the information may have been found to be available in a different way.

Comment: Thank you, if we are in private I would give the login information to you but here I cannot do it in public. I searched the page with my content to find another way to get the information but I was unable to find any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried chaining your actions?

```
movetoelement=css(".content")
action = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
actionoffset = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)   
action.move_to_element(movetoelement).actionoffset.move_by_offset(10,10).perform()
```

Please note that moving your mouse inside browser window tends to break tests like this.

Comment: I tried similar to this, result is same, also before move_by_offset I need to take the time. I cannot use them together like this.

Comment: If anything else fails you can try using robot class in selenium. The main downside is that you won't be able to run this test in parallel.

Comment: Well, thank you it is not python but at last if nothing works, I will try it without python.

Comment: I asked the question with title : "Python Selenium move mouse to element doesn't work" I don't know why they changed it.